# Rescaling `\check` symbol

Tags: symbols, scaling

I would like to rescale `\check` symbol but not for the whole document. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{asana-math}

\begin{document}

this is a normal \check symbol $\check{u}$, but in $\check{U}$ 
I want the check symbol to be larger

\end{document}
```

Comment: How *much* larger would you like the symbol to be?

Comment: the same as `\widehat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mathabx` package provides a `\widecheck` macro.

Since I don't have the `asana-math` package on my system, the following example uses LuaLaTeX and the `unicode-math` package to specify `Asana Math` as the OpenType math font.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx} % for '\widecheck' macro
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Asana Math}
\begin{document}
$\check{u}$ $\widecheck{U}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: the problem is that i need to define my own theorems and so i need to load `\mathtools` in order to use `\newtheorem` command. However, i cannot use both `mathabx` and `mathtools` packages

Comment: @Yorgos - Have you tried loading `mathtools` *before* `mathabx`?

Comment: yes.. i get an error that `\circ` is already defined

Comment: @Yorgos - That's strange -- I get no such error. Which TeX distribution do you use?

Comment: i use TeXLive 2016

Comment: @Yorgos - The loading sequence ordering should be `mathtools`, `mathabx`, `unicode-math` -- or `asana-math`, I suppose, but that's a package I don't have and hence can't test. Is that's what you're doing?

Comment: the problem was that the first package i loaded was `unicode-math`. Thanks for everything!!!

Comment: @Yorgos - Glad this issue got solved in the end.

Comment: standard warning that `mathabx` changes *all* symbols.  to avoid that: [Importing a single symbol from a different font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Excellent advice indeed! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Strangely enough, `unicode-math` doesn't define `\widecheck`; you can do it yourself.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\def\removefixed#1fixed #2\removefixed#3{%
  \protected\def#3{#1 #2}%
}

\AtBeginDocument{\expandafter\removefixed\check\removefixed\widecheck}

\begin{document}

this is a normal \verb|\check| symbol $\check{u}$, but in $\widecheck{U}$
I want the check symbol to be larger

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that was my main concern. i didn't know how possible is to define your own sympbols. i thought that you hane to 'stuck' with its package's symbols

Comment: @Yorgos I think that `unicode-math` *should* provide it.

Comment: i couldn't agree more

Comment: @Yorgos Filed issue report: https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/372